# What is a good geometric reason to care about the Jacobson radical of a ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an arbitrary commutative ring with unit. The nilradical $\mathfrak N = \mathfrak N(R)$ is the intersection of $R$'s prime ideals, hence the closed subset $V(\mathfrak N)$ contains every point of $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, so, in a sense, $\operatorname{Spec}(R/\mathfrak N)$ is the smallest closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ that the raw topology sees as being the whole of $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, i.e., any distinctions can only be seen in the structure sheaf. I see the inclusion $\operatorname{Spec}(R/\mathfrak N) \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ as adding an infinitesimal layer of fat on top of $\operatorname{Spec}(R/\mathfrak N)$, which is just meat and bones. The elements of $R$ and $R/\mathfrak R$ induce the same functions on the same underlying topological space, because we cannot see any nilpotent distinctions by evaluating them at points.

Is there any similar intuition that I could develop for the Jacobson radical? Of course, I can adapt the sentence in the preceding paragraph as follows: $\mathfrak J = \mathfrak J(R)$ is the intersection of $R$'s maximal ideals, hence the closed subset $V(\mathfrak J)$ contains every closed point of $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, so, in a sense, $\operatorname{Spec}(R/\mathfrak J)$ is the smallest closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ that the raw topology sees as containing every closed point of $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$. However, what is a good reason to care about this definition?

Evidently, I am failing to see Nakayama's lemma as a geometric statement.

Comment: Over a Jacobson ring (e.g. a finitely generated commutative $k$-algebra) the two agree so it’s not entirely obvious what the difference is “geometrically.” I guess an example worth keeping in mind is a local domain such as a formal power series ring, where the nilradical vanishes but the Jacobson radical recovers the unique maximal ideal.

Comment: With a noncommutative ring I think the motivation is clearer: the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ consists of all elements which act trivially on all simple modules. This is a pretty natural thing to consider from the point of view of representation theory, say.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan , I think you've made a better explanation of the geometry than you claim - the Jacobson radical is the ideal of functions vanishing at all closed points, while the nilradical is the ideal of functions vanishing at all points. If closed points are dense, then these are the same, but there are plenty of times when we're not in this situation (working over a DVR, for instance).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Ah, I see. I have not had the time to study representation theory (despite meaning to do so for some amount of time already). I will look more into that. Thanks!

Comment: @KReiser: Whoa, that really seems to be the key: “when the closed points are dense”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me attempt to sum up the comments as an answer. The Jacobson radical is the ideal of $R$ consisting of all the functions which evaluate to $0$ at every maximal ideal of $R$, aka the closed points of $\operatorname{Spec} R$, while the nilradical is the ideal of $R$ consisting of all the functions which evaluate to $0$ at every prime ideal, aka every point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$. When we're working over a Jacobson ring $R$, these two notions are the same, because the closed points are dense among all points. Over non-Jacobson rings like DVRs, this is no longer true, and so there are functions which vanish on all the closed points but not all the points, like $t\in k[t]_{(t)}$: it's zero if you evaluate at the closed point, but nonzero at the generic point.